# Stop pytest after X consecutive fails

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Currently pytest has the --maxfail=X flag that stops the whole system after X total fails.

Could someone tell me how I could do the same but instead of total fails, it be X consecutive fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--maxfail parameter`. check in `pytest -h`:

```
pytest --maxfail=num
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better solution, but you could write a script that went through all the test you wanted one by one calling:

```
pass=py.test.main(test)
```

and keeping a counter which resets whenever pass=0 (i.e the tests pass) and throws an exception when the counter reaches X:

```
count=0
for tests:
    pass=py.test.main(test)
    if pass=1: count+=1
    else: count=0
    if count==X BREAK;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking more along the lines of a fixture in the conftest file. But I'll keep this in mind if I can't find something better. Thanks!